# MySQL database is not recreated with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a project that uses mysql, so I've built a container for mysql with docker-compose and it worked. I also have a volume for persistent data and while container is running for the first time it will create a database. However, I droped that database. After running that container again, the database did not recreated. I've tried deleting my container, my image, executed prune process
I've also tried

`docker-compose down`

`docker-compose rm`

`docker-compose stop`

`docker-compose down --rmi all`

I've deleted the volume folder and it didn't help either

This is my folder structer:

```
mysql/
   scripts/
       create_users_table.sql
   data/
docker-compose.yaml
```

And this is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 33060:3306
    volumes:
      - /mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /mysql/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql` container will initialize the database on startup when the `/var/lib/mysql` directory in the container is empty. So to reset the database you need to empty that volume.

Since in your `docker-compose.yml` you have bind-mounted this directory you need to delete all contents in the `/mysql/data` directory of the docker host.